# I have WP multisite, ACM Issued SSL, Load Balancer Setup, how to provide HTTPS access to users?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl

Has anyone with a WP multisite been through this process? I have created the Load Balancer and have a domain (one of the multisite sites) on an EC2 instance.

My load balancer setup looks like this:

[image]

Going to **https://foobar.com** just times out and going to **https://www.foobar.com** just ignores the SSL request. Is there a step I'm missing? Maybe something in **httpd.conf** or **wp-config**?

I'm sure someone has gone through something similar, it would help us all dealing with such an issue. I feel like going with WPEngine would've made much more sense than AWS for an simple WP site :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you load balancer is setup with SSL termination as I can see you're forwarding the traffic to http target group, not https, do you have self-certified SSL.

you wanna make sure in your wp-config.php to detect SSL :

```
// Update 8-April-2018: I moved https redirection from the Apache virtual 
server config to wp-config.php using this snippet.
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

for more details, check the link : https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/wordpress-aws-elb-ssl/

Comment: Our SSL was purchased with AWS Certificate Manager. Would that change anything?

Comment: No, just wanted to make sure you're not using self-verified

Comment: But all the above is doing is replacing HTTP requests with HTTPS that will still lead to broken site. You can see for yourself: https://waclighting.com

Comment: does your target group have  a healthy instance?

Comment: I tried finding an attribute that would indicate healthy instance in AWS load balancer section but no luck. BTW, if you can help me I will edit answer and send you $10 in BitCoin.